# Node Postgresql User Password Security

Tags: node.js, security, passwords

I've created a registration web page and I'm wondering what's the best way to upload password to server and how to store user passwords.

Currently, I just have a field for password and when the user clicks "submit", it makes a call to the server then insert the password into the db as is.

My question is at which step should I encrypt the password and what are some good methods of keeping this data secure?

I've looked around but haven't found much resource on this, maybe I'm not searching the right things.

Answer (score 1):

The popular way of doing this in node is using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) password encoder.

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const myPlaintextPassword = 's0/\/\P4$$w0rD';
const someOtherPlaintextPassword = 'not_bacon';

// hashing
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
});


// comparing
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {
    // result == true
});
```